# jQuery .sortable() cloning elements when it shouldn't

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I've recently added a playlist feature to my website in which a user can drag tracks that they have available into a playlist.

Using jQuery UI 1.8, everything was working fine until i noticed a quirky behavior: the sortable only side is cloning the objects when sorting them. Let me explain the basic structure and then I will link the fiddle.

- There are two parent divs: `#available-tracks-wrapper` and
  `#playlist-wrapper`.
- The user can drag from `#available-tracks-wrapper` on the left and drop
  into `#playlist-wrapper` on the right.
- The user can then sort the tracks as they wish inside of `#playlist-wrapper`.

The problem:

- Upon sort start, the sorting behavior is evident, however, when dropped, the object gets      cloned instead of simply moved.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e34D4/5/). I apologize for the missing images ,etc. But the elements required to reproduce the behavior are still present.

I have scoured the docs in search of an option or method that prevents this behavior to no avail. I did notice this however:

> Enable a group of DOM elements to be sortable. Click on and drag an
>   element to a new spot within the list, and the other items will adjust
>   to fit. **By default, sortable items share draggable properties**.

So i disabled the `helper:'clone'` in `#available-tracks-wrapper`, that indeed removed the cloning behavior, but resulted in worse behavior in other areas.

Next I thought to simply create a function on start or stop to remove the previous element, but targeting that dynamically would prove to be a challenge as `this` or `event.target` is always the parent `#playlist-wrapper` and not the elements themselves.

Thank you all for taking a look at this. I imagine it's simply something I'm overlooking as a result of my noobness.

Comment: I noticed that in the fiddle the clone isn't working properly coming from `#available-tracks-wrapper`, not demonstrating that behavior in my actual application, just fyi I geuss.

Comment: I was informed that these particular jQuery ui elements work best when modeling the markup on the demos as much as possible, so I'm restructuring things. Will post an update either way in case someone else runs across this issue.

Comment: Yep. Was the mark up. Apparently this only works efficiently when transferring <li>'s from one <u/ol> to another.